# R: converting fractions into decimals in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, fractions

I am trying to convert a data frame of numbers stored as characters in a fraction form to be stored as numbers in decimal form. (There are also some integers, also stored as char.) I want to keep the current structure of the data frame, i.e. I do not want a list as a result.

Example data frame (note: the real data frame has all elements as character, here it is a factor but I couldn't figure out how to replicate a data frame with characters):

```
    a <- c("1","1/2","2")
    b <- c("5/2","3","7/2")
    c <- c("4","9/2","5")
    df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I tried `df[] <- apply(df,1, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`. This calculates the numbers correctly, but only for the last column, populating the data frame with that.

Result:

```
   a  b    c
1  4  4.5  5
2  4  4.5  5
3  4  4.5  5
```

I also tried `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))`, which had the following result (and I have no idea why):

```
   a  b  c
1  3  3  2
2  3  3  2
3  3  3  2
```

Desired result:

```
   a   b    c
1  1   2.5  4
2  0.5 3    4.5
3  2   3.5  5
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
df[] <- apply(df, c(1, 2), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
df
    a   b   c
1 1.0 2.5 4.0
2 0.5 3.0 4.5
3 2.0 3.5 5.0

eval(parse(text = x))
```

evaluates one expression at a time so, you need to run cell by cell.

EDIT: if some data frame elements can not be evaluated you can account for that by adding an ifelse statement inside the function:

```
df[] <- apply(df, c(1, 2), function(x) if(x %in% skip){NA} else {eval(parse(text = x))})
```

Where skip is a vector of element that should not be evaluated.

Comment: yes, it was a typo, already deleted the comment. sry for the confusion. your solution works great on the example df, unfortunately neither solutions work yet on my real data. I end up with the correct decimals from the first column pasted sideways repeatedly in the rows..

Comment: I was about to, but when cutting it down I realised that there was one empty column at the very end. After removing it, your code runs magically. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: apart from empty columns which I removed, there are sometimes random empty cells ("") which seem to mess up the result of the function. Could you please help how to modify to function to still work when there are such cells in the dataframe? Thank you

Comment: you could add an `if else` statement like:  `function(x) if(x %in% dont_eval) {NA} else {eval(parse(text = x)))}` and define a `dont_eval` vactor containing `c(NA_character_, "")` and whatever messes with your functions. I can add this to my post if you can provide a new example data frame with problematic values.

Comment: thank you!!  `df[] <- apply(df, c(1, 2), function(x) if(x=="") {NA} else {eval(parse(text = x))})` works great as a final solution. I'm still only learning to code so your help is truly appreciated

Comment: glad I could help, if you found any answer to your question useful please consider marking one as accepted. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

To those looking for a one-liner: you can use `parse_ratio` from the DOSE package to coerce the character fractions to numeric.

```
library(DOSE)

b <- c("5/2","3","7/2")
parse_ratio(b)
[1] 2.5 1.0 3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, you should prevent your characters from turning into factors in `data.frame()`

   df <- data.frame(a, b, c, stringsAsFactors = F)

   Then you can wrap a simple `sapply/lapply` inside your `lapply` to achieve what you want.

   ```
   sapply(X = df, FUN = function(v) {
                                 sapply(X = v,
                                        FUN = function(w) eval(parse(text=w)))
                                }
     )
   ```

   **Side Notes**
2. If you feed `eval` an improper expression such as `expression(1, 1/2, 2)`, that evaluates to last value. This explains the `4 4.5 5` output. A proper `expression(c(1, 1/2, 2))` evaluates to the expected answer.
3. The code `lapply(df, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))` returns a `3 3 2` because `sapply(data.frame(a,b,c), as.numeric)` returns:

   ```
        a b c
   [1,] 1 2 1
   [2,] 2 1 3
   [3,] 3 3 2
   ```

   These numbers correspond to the `levels()` of the factors, through which you were storing your fractions.

Comment: Your solutions works great, and the answer was also very educational. Thank you very much